# Short form for multiline equation

Tags: environments

Is there a short form to go into and leave an environment that supports multi-line equations (and alignment with `&`)?

I'm looking for the multi-line equivalent of `\[ equation \]`.

Comment: `align` has 5 letters, how short do you need?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please have a look at the [`amsmath` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), as well.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! See the `amsmath` package for several environments of this form including `align`.  Avoid `eqnarray`.

Comment: @David, I would type `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` right? So actually that is quite a few letters. I'll interpret your question non rhetorical and answer it: two or three symbols. Preferably ones that logically seem to open and close an environment. This is aids readability a lot. Commands such as `\[`  and `\]` make the document much clearer in my opinion.

Comment: environment syntax is pervasive in latex, it doesn't help to hide it, most editors will allow you to add such an envirnment in a few keystrokes, it is 3 or 5 keystrokes to enter `\begin{align}  \end{align}` for example in the editor I use (depending if it guesses whether I want align next)

Comment: It's more an editor problem – defining shortcuts to insert `\begin{environment}`, `end{environment}` and the cursor in between.

Comment: @David, it isn't about hiding it. It is also isn't so much about the keystrokes although I wouldn't mind on saving on those too (yes an editor can help here but I prefer to do my own typing). My main concern is with readability. The fact is that our mind (or at least my mind) can much more quickly understand symbolic language than actual language especially if the symbols are chosen well to mimic patterns we are already familiar with, such as opening and closing brackets.

Comment: (cont'd) The fact that exactly the kind of command I like is available for equations indicates firstly that I'm not unique in this and secondly that this should also be possible for slight variations of equations.

Comment: Computer users tend to fall into two groups: those who hate to type and those who hate to memorize.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

`<rant>`You can redefine TeX to make it do most things but this doesn't mean that you should! Readability is also a subjective standard: if you have non-standard short-hands in your files then, for example, you will find it more difficult to write papers/documents with coauthors who won't know your commands - and some journals will object to the code as well. As suggested in the comments, I think that the best approach here is to let your editor do the work: environments are so common in LaTeX that having a standard method for creating them makes sense.

I don't recommend using this but,`</rant>` if you really want to define short-hands for common alignment environments then one way to do it is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\def\BA#1\EA{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}

  \BA
      f(x) &= \int_\pi^x g(x)\, dx\\
      h(x) &= \int_\pi^x f(x)\, dx
  \EA

\end{document}
```

This produces the expected output:

[image]

In particular, you cannot just define `\BA` to be `\begin{align}` and `\EA` to be `\end{align}` because the AMS alignment environments do some fancy things that require them to look ahead and find the matching `\end{align}`. The way that I have defined `\BA...\EA` above means that this "looking ahead" will now happen twice, so it's not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid littering your file with custom commands, try typing `\bal` then pressing `TAB` or `ESC` (you can change which key autocompletes in your editor's settings)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).